# Why are instances instantiated differently during debug and release?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, compiler-optimization

Until now, when implementing the singleton pattern, I used one of the following two variations:

```
public class ClassX
{
    private static ClassX _instance1;
    public static ClassX Instance1 {
        get {
            if (_instance1 == null) {
                _instance1 = new ClassX();
            }

            return _instance1;
        }
    }


    public static readonly ClassX Instance2 = new ClassX();
}
```

In the first version it is obvious when the instance is created: first call to the public property.

The second one I considered to be a convenient shorthand that I used, if possible (e.g. the class requires no non-constant parameters) and I didn't really need to bother about knowing exactly when the instance is created. And didn't, assuming the compiler would trace dependencies accordingly etc...

But it turns out that order and timing of the creation of `Instance2` differ, depending on the build: debug or release.

I imagine/assume it has something to do with optimizations the compiler makes for either scenario, but I was wondering, if anyone could shed some more light on the issue.

And: can the compiler be taught to treat both the same (regarding this issue)? Should I always use the first syntax? Or look more into `Lazy<T>`?

Thanks!

Comment: Would probably be useful to indicate how they are differing.

Comment: You'll probably want to read [this](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Singleton.aspx).

Comment: I don't see a static constructor, so according to [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645758(v=vs.71).aspx): "... static field initializers are executed at an implementation-dependent time prior to the first use of a static field of that class.". More info [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10775219/static-field-initialization-in-debug-and-release-build), which looks like a duplicate actually. Your question is about when static fields are initialized, not when "instances are instantiated" which IMO is related to constructors and not static fields.

Comment: Your property implementation is not thread-safe.  So you could end up with more than one instance and not a true singleton.  If you go that route you'll need to add synchronization.  Usually via `lock`.  But if it was me I would use a static constructor.  Easy and fool-proof.

Comment: And yes it seems clear you are trying to make a singleton of sorts (that has more than one instance I guess..), so I would also read [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650316.aspx).

Comment: @EvanTrimboli: In release mode the instance is created later than in debug mode. Actually it helped make me aware of a race-condition I had overlooked. Using the first, longer, syntax all is fine.

Comment: @Zer0: Thanks for mentioning that, very true. But (despite the overlooked race-conditiono) this isn't an issue in my particular context.